# Extra space after grid cell, don't know where it is comming from

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm building a sample project, I have created a grid container but soon after first cell (header), it is adding twice gutter as for other rows. 
Here is css

```
.container {
background-color:#fff;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(6rem, 1fr) [center-start] 
repeat(auto-fit, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 14rem) [col-end]) [center- 
end]  minmax(6rem, 1fr)  [full-end];
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, min-content);
grid-row-gap: 8rem;  
}
```

I think it is better if you check the original page and inspect it from there. 
Link to my page on github [sample project cool-portfolio](https://hassanraja447.github.io/cool-portfolio/)

Comment: Please share your HTML too. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I thought HTML would be too long that's why I shared the link to the project, but next time I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .content class you have " grid-row: 3;" and then " grid-row: 4;" in .portfolio and so on for .contact and .footer  You should start at "grid-row:2;" for .content "grid-row:3;" for .portfolio and so on.